# Does YouTube embedded players supports being loaded in a cross origin isolated site?

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, youtube-api, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-opener-policy

## Summary

My Site requires the [SharedArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer) support. Therefore we need to enable [Cross-Origin Isolation](https://web.dev/cross-origin-isolation-guide/) on our site, which will be depreciated primarily on Chrome starting Chrome 92. However, apparently, Youtube embed URLs do not appear to have support for sites that enable Cross-Origin Isolation?

Attached below it mentions that the cross-origin-resource-policy is not set and blocked by the cross-origin isolation, from the YouTube embed document.

[image: cross-origin]

My question is that is it actually not supported or there is an option that I am missing to make youtube embed works on a cross-origin isolated site? Otherwise, I'll need to figure out some other workarounds.

Comment: I've been searching for an answer to this as well. Did you manage to find something?

Comment: No, been wondering for months now, and still relying on the origin trial. May need to work around it eventually.

Comment: You might be interested in this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240387105 on the YouTube API service.
Consider commenting and upvoting to increase the chance of seeing a fix soon.